# Optical Character Recognition Python Code ignoring all characters completely for some images

Tags: python, image, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I am currently working on a simple task where I have to read characters from simple images. Used tesseract in python to write following code which works on all simple and complex images having English text but fails on a particular image, can anyone tell me why the following python code can not read characters from the following image , as you can see with 6 black sections having 6 characters in each box, character colour is white.

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import argparse
import cv2
import os

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i","--image",required=True,help="path to input image to be OCR'd")
ap.add_argument("-p","-- preprocess",type=str,default="thresh",help="type of preprocessing to be done")
args=vars(ap.parse_args())
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
gray2 = cv2.BackgroundSubtractor()
gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray2 = cv2.threshold(gray2, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
rectKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9, 3))
sqKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 5))
if args["preprocess"] == "thresh":
    gray2 = cv2.threshold(gray2, 2, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
elif args["preprocess"] == "blur":
    gray2 = cv2.medianBlur(gray2,3)
filename = "{}.png".format(os.getpid())
cv2.imwrite(filename,gray2)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename))
print(text)
```

[If this image is used, it gives perfect result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkPnK.png)

0123456789
ABCDEFGHIJKL
MNOPQRSTUV
WXYZ

When I am trying to use the following image ,

[Processed Image which does not give result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c72PF.png)
**the code completely ignores all characters in the image.  The only difference is the first image does not have boxes like the second image where each black box contains 6 characters**

***Can someone please help and tell me what am I missing why this code fails for the second image, Thanks.***

Here are the original images :
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiho0.png)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59GrP.jpg)

Comment: Are those images result of your preprocessing (= what you feed to tesseract) or do you apply your preprocessing code to them?

Comment: I feed these images to tesseract for processing from command prompt using like 
python testocr.py -i filename.png

Comment: What is testocr.py?

Comment: name of python file in which this code is saved

Comment: Than please add to the question images which you feed to tesseract (result of `cv2.imwrite(filename,gray2)`)

Comment: added images at preprocessing stage as image1 and image2 at the end, images in the main post are the images which python code processes and later I saved them as png image files.

Comment: Try inverting image colors (`gray2 = cv2.bitwise_not(gray2)`)before you call `cv2.imwrite(filename,gray2)
`

Comment: I already tried that, doesn't help